# Shift array elements one level to the right (down one level) when using foreach

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Sorry if there's an obvious answer, but I've been trying for hours to google the solution and tried various ways. Basically I'm trying to shift an array within a multidimensional array one level to the right. The output array is to be fed into a program which only accepts the desired format of multidimensional array.

We have ($result):

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [id] => 1
        [data] => AAA
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [id] => 2
        [data] => BBB
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [id] => 3
        [data] => CCC
    )
)
```

We want to insert a new array [test] in between the multidimensional array. Desired result:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [test] => Array (
            [id] => 1
            [data] => AAA
        )
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [test] => Array (
            [id] => 2
            [data] => BBB
        )
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [test] => Array (
            [id] => 3
            [data] => CCC
        )
    )
)
```

What I've got so far:

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    $newarray[] = array($key => $value)
};

return $newarray;
```

Unfortunately the above inserts an incremental index instead of [test] where we want it to.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    $newarray[$key] = ['test' => $value];
};
```

Comment: That's it! It's such a simple solution. Thank you so much!

Comment: Note that the semi-colon afther the `foreach` cycle is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a loop and index in the same array using the current key. Then update the value with a new array where using `test` as the key and `$v` as the value.

```
$arrays = [
    0 => [
        "id" => 1,
        "data" => "AAA"
    ],
    1 => [
        "id" => 2,
        "data" => "BBB"
    ],
    2 => [
        "id" => 3,
        "data" => "CCC"
    ],
];


foreach ($arrays as $k => $v) {
    $arrays[$k] = ['test' => $v];
};

print_r($arrays);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [test] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [data] => AAA
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [test] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [data] => BBB
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [test] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [data] => CCC
                )

        )

)
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/Rrrdm)

Comment: This does a full copy of the data, that might create issues with non trivial data volumes.

Comment: Possible, but I'd expect this to throw a notice for an undefined `$arrays[$k]` when you try to assign a new value. But I am not familiar with the current stand, `php` unfortunately still changes a lot...

Comment: I'd say `$arrays[$k] = ['test' => $v];` without the prior call to `unset()` is more elegant and easier to read. But that certainly is a personal preference.

Comment: @arkascha Of course! You can just overwrite the value using the current key. Thank you.

Comment: I like your answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

This would be a working and flexible approach:

```
<?php
$data = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'data' => "AAA"
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'data' => "BBB"
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3,
        'data' => "CCC"
    ]
];

array_walk($data, function(&$entry) {
    $entry = [
        'test' => $entry
    ];
});

print_r($data);
```

The output obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [test] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [data] => AAA
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [test] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [data] => BBB
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [test] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [data] => CCC
                )

        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'data' => "AAA"
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'data' => "BBB"
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3,
        'data' => "CCC"
    ]
];


$newArray = array_map(function ($value) {
    return ['test' => $value];
}, $data);

var_dump($newArray);
```

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Comment: Do you really need `array_reduce()` for this? Isn't `array_map()` sufficient?

Comment: @Barmar full ack. array_map works, too and is much easier to read. Answer amended.